# URL Hacking to create user record

Tags: urlhacking

I have created a formula field, which allows me to click on an image to then create a new user record, based on what has been entered on a case.

This is the formula:

```
HYPERLINK("/005/e?& Email =  Case.New_User_Email__c  ", IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015E0000009ELB5","Create new user record]"), "_blank")
```

So, I have my `case` object, which contains the field `New_User_Email__c`. I want to take that field and then populate the `Email` field on the `User` object.

When I now click on the button that I created in my formula, I only get an empty user record. The url that is shown in the browser is as follows: `/005/e?&%20Email%20=%20%20Case.New_User_Email__c`

Any ideas what is wrong with my formula?
Tia, Lily.

Answer (score 2):

Change the formula as below,

```
HYPERLINK("/005/e?& Email =  Case.New_User_Email__c  ", IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015E0000009ELB5","Create new user record]"), "_blank")
```

To

```
HYPERLINK("/005/e?Email="&Case.New_User_Email__c, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015E0000009ELB5","Create new user record]"), "_blank")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I changed it to 'HYPERLINK("/005/e?Email="&New_User_Email__c, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015E0000009ELB5","Create new user record]"), "_blank")' as it did not like 'case' in the formula

Comment: It seems that now I am stuck again, when I want to add a second field. This time, it looks like this: `HYPERLINK("/005/e?Email="&New_User_Email__c& "?Status__c="& User_Status__c, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015E0000009ELB5","Create new user record]"), "_blank")`. I am not sure how to link a second field into the URL - are you able to help?